# Cannot get a JavaScript program to add odd numbers

Tags: javascript

Here's the problem:

Create a sum program that calculates the sum of all odd numbers between 1 and the number entered by the user. For example if the user enters in the number 7 the program would calculate 1 + 3 + 5 + 7. The total and the expression should be displayed on the document. The answer would be 16.

My code so far

```
//declare the variables

var sternum = prompt("enter a number");
var tantalum = 1;
var increase = 1;
var expression = "+";

//finding the sum
document.write(" the sum of all numbers are: ");
do {
  if(sternum % 2 == 0) {
  }
  else{
    document.write(increase + expression);
    increase = increase + 1;
    tantalum = tantalum + increase;
  }
}while(increase < sternum); 

document.write(sternum + " = " + tantalum);
```

Comment: Don't use `document.write`.

Comment: `if(sternum % 2 == 0)` this creates an infinite loop because you are not incrementing `increase`...

Answer (score 1):

You have created an infinite loop. Make sure you increment `increase` every iteration:

```js
var sternum = prompt("enter a number");
var tantalum = 0;
var increase = 1;
var expression = "+";

 //finding the sum
 document.write(" the sum of all numbers are: ");
 do {
     if(increase % 2 == 0) {
     }
     else{
       document.write(increase + expression);
       tantalum = tantalum + increase;
     }
     increase = increase + 1;
 }while(increase <= sternum); 

 document.write(" = " + tantalum);
```

To make it more efficient you could change `increase = increase + 1;` to `increase = increase + 2;`. No need to process even numbers. Also `tantalum` should be set to `0` to start.